# What SSD can I replace Seagate model: ST500LT012-1DG142 HDD?

Tags: upgrade, hard-drive

I have laptop with Seagate model: ST500LT012-1DG142 HDD.

What kind of parameters should I look for, to buy an SSD to replace the HDD?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shopping recommendations are offtopic here

Comment: Please, don't recommend the specific model of ssd, just needed parameters.

Comment: I am voting to close this because this is not a Ubuntu question.

Comment: In case you are running Ubuntu, and need help setting up Ubuntu in the new SSD, please ask a new question with the specific problem you are facing.

Comment: Lubuntu is presently installed. I have understood I need to know the size of the HDD, and the sort of the port. I found that it is 2.5 inch SATA. You can close question. Thanks to Achisman Panigrahi.

Answer (score 2):

Open your laptop and check out what kind of port the HDD is using (most likely it will be SATA).

Check out whether the HDD is 2.5 inch (most likely) or 3.5 inch. Then buy an SSD with the same port and and same size.